# Refunds Using Paypal's Delayed Chained Payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I am currently developing a web application which is a booking system for events.

Basically i want to use PayPal's Delayed Chained Payments system to do this:

1. BUYER makes a purchase through web app
2. ADMIN is the primary receiver of the funds
3. SELLER receives the funds 7 days after the event has occurred (less commission for ADMIN)

The reason i am leaving a 7 day period until the SELLER receives the funds is to allow for refunds and cancellations.

**My question is:
Does the API allow me to interveen the delayed payment before the 7 days has elapsed, thus cancelling the payment to the SELLER and allow me to directly refund the BUYER the full amount.** This is my ideal situation as it means their will not be the problem of the SELLERS account not having sufficient funds for the refund.

If anyone could help it would be great!

Answer (score 2):

With Delayed Chained Payments you'll have the ability to cancel or execute the payment whenever you need to (within 90 days). So if the seller isn't able to supply the product to the buyer (or whatever reason) you can cancel the transaction.

Submitting a refund after a payment has been executed is a little tricky.

So to do a refund for a Chained Payment transaction you'll need to use the Permission Services API calls for the receivers to allow you to process refunds on their behalf. If they don't, you cannot refund the payment sent to another recipient.

Comment: I want to execute payment after partial refund but paymeny execution is not working and showing error i.e.   [error(0).message] => The payment(s) to the secondary receiver(s) cannot be executed because the status of the payment to the primary receiver is REFUNDED .

Answer (score 1):

After make delayed chained payment  if you are not execute payment to secondary receiver then you can refund full amount of payment using refund api Call but you need to grand third party access .using grant api access

Comment: I want to execute payment after partial refund but paymeny execution is not working and showing error i.e.   [error(0).message] => The payment(s) to the secondary receiver(s) cannot be executed because the status of the payment to the primary receiver is REFUNDED .